# Does drools support any form of "rule activation probability" (as in how close to firing is a rule)?

Tags: drools

I'm wondering if there is anything in drools that can be used to determine how close a rule is (or has been) to being activated?
From all that I can tell, the standard drools doesn't support anything like it, I just wondered if I might have missed something.

I glanced at Drools Chance (https://github.com/droolsjbpm/drools-chance), but it seems that it hasn't been developed a lot anymore recently and doesn't seem ready for Drools 6.x.

I know that AgendaEventListeners can be used to intercept when a rule has fired but it doesn't look like there is anything to intercept if a single condition of a rule has been evaluated to true.

Am I missing something or is this a current limitation of drools to not have any support for this kind of thing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related what I called "learning the reason for failure". Consider that you have to pass n qualifications. Rather than being told that you have failed you'd like to have a list of the "pass" (and "fail") criteria.

One rule evaluating all of this in a lump sum is no good. You have to write one rule for each of the n criteria and collect the positives with the fact holding the properties under survey. Finally, one low-priority rule can check whether you have all n ("hooray") and another one can tell you "sorry, no", but it *can give you a list what succeeded* (and what not).

Lots of effort, but good information is always costly.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could use a work around.  Construct a set of extra rules that write metrics for when they fire depending on your definition of close--that could be 1..n parts of the LHS for the rule of interest and/or thresholds for nearness to any part of the LHS (say you want to know when a value approaches to with 90% of another value).  For complex conditionals in source code (not Drools related), I've used approaches like the below to trace complicated and nested logic:

```
boolean a1 = property1 > property2
boolean a2 = (!isHigh || isMedium)
boolean a3 = property 4 == property5
System.out.println ("rule2:  " + a1 + " " + a2 + " " + a3);
if (a1 && a2 && a3) {
   ...do something
}
```